# Pass multidimensional array to functions in c causes stack overflow

Tags: c, arrays, exception, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "funcs.h"
void func1(int (*codes)[1296][2]);
void func2(int arr0[]);
void func4(int (*codes)[1296][2],int arr3[]);
int func5(int isValid[]);
void func6(int (*codes)[1296][2],int arr3[],int var0);
void func7(int arr2[]);
void func8(int arr1[],int idx);
void func1()
{
....
}
```

where `codes` is a 3d array of size 1296 x 1296 x 2. When I try compiling my code I get, even after `void func1`, unhandled exception and stack overflow. Why does it happen? How can I send `codes` to each of my functions?

**EDIT:** I mustn't use:

- any libs except stdio.h
- any global or static variables

That's all the restrictions as far as I know.

Comment: Why do you need a 3D array that big? The problem is getting the array allocated at all. Once you've got it allocated, passing it to the functions isn't a problem, but getting it allocated is.  Which system are you on (oh, Windows is mentioned in a comment)? Can you increase the stack size for a program on your system?

Comment: because I am writing mastermind (4^6=1296). I'm using windows 7 professional 64 bits. how can i increase the stack size?

Comment: My immediate reaction is "Rethink your algorithm — you are doing it wrong".  It is very far from clear why you'd need that many items. What are you doing with that array? What's the third dimension for (2). Come to that, what are you doing with the second dimension?

Comment: i tried another way using 2d arrays and i got timeout from their system.

Comment: 4^6 = 4096.  use the bit(or nibble) instead of int.

Answer (score 1):

An array of 1296 x 1296 x 2 elements of type `int` requires somewhat over 8 MiB of stack, which is more than is allowed on some systems. On Mac OS X (10.9.1), the default stack size is 8 MiB.

Either use `malloc()` or one of its ilk to allocate the array, or allocate the array statically instead of on the stack.

Comment: i mustnt use malloc and im indeed on windows.

Comment: If you can't use `malloc()`, then you'll have to make a static allocation of the array.  Either define the array outside any function (with or without the keyword `static`), or define it inside a function with the keyword `static`.

Comment: I also cannot use static or global variables.

Comment: For crying out loud! Put all the wretched teacher-imposed conditions in the question up front so we know what nonsense we (you) are having to deal with.  This is like extracting hens teeth!

Comment: sorry. These were the only two conditions. added them to the question.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question; please note that such limitations are crucial for people to understand.  You're hosed unless you can increase the space available on your program stack, or reduce the size of the array. What are you doing that requires such a big array, or did the size get specified by the teacher too?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43393/discussion-between-coargu-aliquis-and-jonathan-leffler)

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error must be caused because you allocate more stack than your system allows.  So if you statically allocate big arrays like the ones you seem to require (judging from the code you showed) you are likely to run out of stack memory fast.

The code you showed cannot be the cause of this error; it's only function prototypes. So check the static memory allocation in your code.

Also consider using the heap -> dynamically allocate memory <- to get rid of this error.